# Nested v-for access from clicked child element to parent element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

How can I access to parent clicked element from child element `@click` method?

eg:

```
<div v-for="(item, ,index) in bubles">
  {{item.name}}
  <div v-for="subItem in item.bubles">
    <a @click="openModal(subItem)">{{subItem.name}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

here in method `openModal()` I want to get the parent element of `subItem`, so clicked item in parent `v-for`:

```
openModal(subItem) {
  console.log(subItem)
}
```

Comment: Maybe simply pass the parent object as argument `<a @click="openModal(subItem, item)">{{subItem.name}}</a>`?

Comment: I tried but not worked

Comment: It's so interesting but not worked :/ anyway thanks

Comment: *Search your conscience* :-) Vue stuff doesn't like talking to other vue stuff. Children shouldn't care about there parents. There has to be a better way of doing this. Perhaps the event should be handled in the parent, or perhaps the child should directly update the global state, and the view will update "automatically". Extracting state into a global variable is so easy in Vue that there's really no excuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your event handler to openModal (without the brackets and parameters). Then define your method to receive an event like so:

```
<a @click="openModal">{{subItem.name}}</a>

openModal(event) {
 // use event.target to get the element and then you can *walk* the dom
}
```

You can use element attributes to get your subitem.

You can also consider just passing an ID through.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, Pass dynamic value to the click event and capture it in 'methods' object.

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  },
 methods: {
   openModal: function(message) {
     console.log(message);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <a @click='openModal(item.message)'>{{item.message}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on [Melas' solution](/a/54071017/3634538) and provide some demo. Credit goes to [Melas](/users/8676496/).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      bubles: [{
          name: 'item 1',
          bubles: [
            { name: 'item 1.1' }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'item 2',
          bubles: [
            { name: 'sub-item 2.1' },
            { name: 'sub-item 2.2' },
            { name: 'sub-item 2.3' }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'item 3',
          bubles: [
            { name: 'sub-item 3.1' },
            { name: 'sub-item 3.2' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    openModal(evt) {
      if (evt.target) {
        // Not recommended, but you get the idea
        let parent = evt.target.parentElement.parentElement;

        // If you don't need to support IE, use this instead
        // parent = evt.target.closest('.parent-buble');

        parent.classList.add('highlight');

        // For demo purposes only
        setTimeout(() => {
          parent.classList.remove('highlight');
        }, 1000);

        console.log(parent);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div.buble {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.buble.highlight {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.child-buble {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.child-buble:active {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in bubles" :key="item.name" class="buble parent-buble">
    {{item.name}}

    <div v-for="subItem in item.bubles" :key="subItem.name" class="buble child-buble">
      <a @click="openModal($event)">{{subItem.name}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```